# jQuery UI autocomplete combobox in a modal dialog

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, autocompletebox

I want to use a autocomplete combobox http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox within a modal dialog.  However whenever I click on the down arrow (of the combobox) it causes a refresh that results in my modal window closing.

How do I stop the refresh from occuring?  (I am still new to jQuery)

I am using UI 1.8 and jQuery 1.4.1.

Comment: In my case it is the autocomplete that closes, not the modal dialog. Will your solution be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed my own problem by removing the form tag from around the combobox

Answer (score 1):

The problem is discussed on the jQuery forum here:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-combobox-problem-when-it-is-placed-inside-a-form-tag

They suggest several different ways of adjusting the source code of the autocomplete combo to fix it. The simplest one seems to be this:

Change the line that says

```
$("<button>&nbsp;</button>")
```

to

```
$("<button type=\"button\">&nbsp;</button>")
```

this prevents the `type="submit"` from being inserted into the final button.

Comment: I am using jqueryui-1.8.7.js and jquery-1.7.js