# jQuery UI autocomplete combobox - prevent form submit

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm using the nifty 'combobox' variant of jQuery UI Autocomplete - see here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox

I have it within a Form element because its part of a form.

The Autocomplete Combobox has a `<button>` that is used to show the whole drop down list. However when the user presses it, the form submits. This appears to be because the `<button>` has a `type="submit"` attribute. The whole element is created by the `button()` call within the `.combobox` fn, see s[ource code](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#combobox).

How do I stop it submitting?

(NB: [This guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535240/jquery-ui-autocomplete-combobox-in-a-modal-dialog) had the same problem but he fixed it by removing the `form` - I can't do that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, nevermind, I figured it out.

The problem is discussed on the jQuery forum here:
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/autocomplete-combobox-problem-when-it-is-placed-inside-a-form-tag

They suggest several different ways of adjusting the source code of the autocomplete combo to fix it. The simplest one seems to be this:

Change the line that says

```
$("<button>&nbsp;</button>")
```

to

```
$("<button type=\"button\">&nbsp;</button>")
```

this prevents the `type="submit"` from being inserted into the final button.

Comment: It didnt work me on Chrome and FF.                        this.button = $("<button type=\"button\">&nbsp;</button>")
    .attr( "tabIndex", -1 )